# Inserting additional Y axis value in Python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to insert the Y value of a horizontal line in a python plot. My plot is shown below. The value I want to display is the solid black line at Y= 1.035, so essentially I want it display 1.035 just above the 1.0 on the y axis. How could I do do this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try plotting a line with these two points:

```
x = 0, y = 1.035

x = 90, y = 1.035
```

Comment: Plotting the line isn't the problem, I have the line plotted! I just want its Y axis value displayed on the Y axis.